# Android Ads with AdMob and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm trying to add a smaller banner image to the bottom of one of the pages in my app. I'm running into a sort of loopy problem:

The code in the XML file is:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.sidekickz.myadventure.activity_hero_picture.xml"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I've tried all variations of xmlns:app/android/ads but I either run into the issue of all the "android" tags not being supported, or something else.

```
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "appnumber");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("appnumberthing");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But at BEST my app shows an image saying that the ad size isn't set. If I follow the suggestions online to alter it, doing so results in Adsize and AdUnitId need to be set before loading.

Any help would be awesome and you would deserve a hug.

Thanks